# How to extract one column to another file from a 300GB file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, readline

Problem was the huge data number, and I have to do it with my personal laptop with 12GB RAM. I tried a loop with 1M. lines every round, and used csv.writer. But csv.writer wrote like 1M. lines every two hours. So, any other ways worth to try?

```
        lines = 10000000
        for i in range(0, 330):
            list_str = []
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                line_flag = 0
                for _ in range(i*lines):
                    next(f)
                for line in f:
                    line_flag = line_flag + 1
                    data = json.loads(line)['name']
                    if data != former_str:
                        list_str.append(data)
                        former_str = data
                    if line_flag == lines:
                        break
            with open(self.path + 'data_range\\names.csv', 'a', newline='') as writeFile:
                writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter='\n')
                writer.writerow(list_str)
                writeFile.close()
```

another version

```
def read_large_file(f):
    block_size = 200000000
    block = []
    for line in f:
        block.append(line[:-1])
        if len(block) == block_size:
            yield block
            block = []

    if block:
        yield block


def split_files():
    with open(write_file, 'r') as f:
        i = 0
        for block in read_large_file(f):
            print(i)
            file_name = write_name + str(i) + '.csv'
            with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as f_:
                writer = csv.writer(f_, delimiter='\n')
                writer.writerow(block)
            i += 1
```

This was after it read a block and writing ... I wonder how come the rate of data trasmission was keeping about 0.
[image]

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried that takes 2hours for a million rows?

Comment: Thanks, did it ^^

Comment: I would give dask a try. Good starting point: https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily `O(N^2)`, due to repeatedly re-reading the lines you've already read. Open the file once, then loop reading 330 lines at a time, then processing that chunk. Also, I don't see `csv.readline` anywhere; you seem to have a JSONL input file.

Comment: @Amadan I tried the loop inside the file, but I always get me a Error, I guessed we cannot write the data into another file while opening the file?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data. You can do so with `less <file>` if the file is too big, or simply `head <file>`.

Comment: @FloranGmehlin did it^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
import json
import csv

with open(read_file, 'rt') as r, open(write_file, 'wt', newline='') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for line in r:
        writer.writerow([json.loads(line)['name']])
```

> I tried the loop inside the file, but I always get me a Error, I guessed we cannot write the data into another file while opening the file?

You totally can write data in one file while reading another. I can't tell you more about your error until you post what it said, though.

There was a bit in your code about `former_str` which is not covered under "extract one column", so I did not write anything about it.

Comment: the ```former_str``` was to compare if two string one after another are the same. Your code totally sovle my problem! Thanks a lot!! But I am wondering, actually with my code it read quite fast, just csv.writer is damm slow, Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: "read quite fast, just csv.writer is damm slow" — How do you know that?

Comment: because I printed i in every loop, and printed some strings before and after csv.write

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

Essentially using a generator to avoid reading the entire file in memory, and writing the data one line at a time.

```
import jsonlines  # pip install jsonlines
from typing import Generator

def gen_lines(file_path: str, col_name: str) -> Generator[str]:
    with jsonline.open(file_path) as f:
        for obj in f:
            yield obj[col_name]


# Here you can also change to writing a jsonline again
with open(output_file, "w") as out:
     for item in gen_lines(your_file_path, col_name_to_extract):
         out.write(f"{item}\n")
```

Comment: I tried a similar version like this, but it was the same, no problem with reading, but when it strated to write, no reaction within an hour :/ I added the code above as well